# Javascript creating json object from two strings

Tags: javascript, json, string, nightwatch.js

So I will start with my needs. I have a task to create json output using nightwatch.js from the ul list where inside lists are few div elements with classes like name, surname... But really I can't think of any of solutions. Here is my html

```
    <html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<body>
<ul class="random">
    <li class="list">
        <div class="name">John</div>
        <div class="surname">Lewis</div>
    </li>

    <li class="list odd">
        <div class="name">Nick</div>
        <div class="surname">Kyrgios</div>
    </li>

</ul>
</body>
</html>
```

And here is my nightwatch.js script

```
'Test' : function(browser) {

    function iterate(elements) {
      elements.value.forEach(function(el) {
        browser.elementIdText(el.ELEMENT, function(r) {

         browser.elementIdAttribute(el.ELEMENT, 'class', function(att){

          // output for json i guess

           console.log(att.value + ' => ' + r.value) 

         })

        });
      });
    }

    browser
      .url('http://url.com/nightwatch.php')
      .waitForElementVisible('body', 8000)
      .elements('css selector', 'ul li div', iterate)
      .end();
  }
```

Basically this will execute the following:

1. name => John
2. surname => Lewis
3. name => Nick
4. surname => Kyrgios

Output is a string for both...

And how can I make it like

```
[{name: "John", surname: "Lewis"}, {name: "Nick", surname: "Kyrgios"}]
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work. You just need to keep track of the object and place it inside the array after list.

```
function iterate(elements) {
  var objArr = [];
  var obj = {};
  elements.value.forEach(function(el, idx) {
    browser.elementIdText(el.ELEMENT, function(r) {

     browser.elementIdAttribute(el.ELEMENT, 'class', function(att){

       if (obj.hasOwnProperty(att.value)) {
         objArr.push(obj);
         obj = {};
       }
       obj[att.value] = r.value;
     });

    });
    if (idx === (elements.value.length-1)) {
      objArr.push(obj);
      console.log(objArr);
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: This returns just empty array = []

Comment: Ah yes, I had a typo. Should be fixed now.

Comment: But still, empty array. ;)

Comment: Try the update again, haha. I don't have nightwatch or node setup so I can't really test.

Comment: New output `[ { name: 'John', surname: 'Lewis' } ]` but the second list isn't showing

Comment: This should be it!

Comment: Now again empty array => `[ {} ]`

Comment: So any more options?

Comment: Now the output is `[] [ { name: 'John', surname: 'Lewis' } ]`

Answer (score 0):

As with Will's solution, I used straight JavaScript. It does not appear that the nightwatch.js code for this provides any significant benefit. In addition, your question does not specify that only nightwatch.js should be used.

As opposed to Will, I have assumed that the `class` on your inner `<div>` elements could be arbitrary and that the arbitrary class should be used as the key/property on the object for that entry. Choosing to use this method vs. restricting it only to a `name` or `surname` property will depend on what your HTML really is, and how you want to handle classes which are not those two strings.

```js
var theList = [];
var listItems = document.querySelectorAll('li');
for (var itemIndex=0,itemLength=listItems.length; itemIndex < itemLength; itemIndex++) {
  var entry = {};
  divs = listItems[itemIndex].querySelectorAll('div');
  for (var divsIndex=0, divsLength=divs.length; divsIndex < divsLength; divsIndex++) {
    entry[divs[divsIndex].className] = divs[divsIndex].textContent;
  }
  theList.push(entry);
}
outputJson = JSON.stringify(theList);

console.log(outputJson);
```

```html
<html>
<meta charset="utf-8">

<body>
  <ul class="random">
    <li class="list">
      <div class="name">John</div>
      <div class="surname">Lewis</div>
    </li>

    <li class="list odd">
      <div class="name">Nick</div>
      <div class="surname">Kyrgios</div>
    </li>

  </ul>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

What about something like this?

```
  function iterate(elements) {
      var jsonArray = [];
      var jsonBuffer = "";
      elements.value.forEach(function(el) {
        browser.elementIdText(el.ELEMENT, function(r) {

         browser.elementIdAttribute(el.ELEMENT, 'class', function(att){

          // output for json i guess

          if (att.value == 'name') {
            jsonBuffer += "{" + att.value + ":" + "" + r.value + "" + ",";
          }
          else {
            jsonBuffer += att.value + ":" + "" + r.value + "" + "}";
            jsonArray.push(jsonBuffer);
            jsonBuffer = "";
          }

         })

        });
      });
      var jsonOutput = "[";
      var i = 0;
      jsonArray.forEach(function(el) {
        if (i < jsonArray.length) {
          jsonOutput += el + ",";
        } else {
          jsonOutput += el + "]";
        }
        i++;
      }
    }
```

Comment: Nope, still nothing! Now when I write console.log(jsonOutput); there is only [

Answer (score -1):

I'm not familiar with Nightwatch, but you essentially loop through the elements and push them on to an array.

```js
var results = [];
var entries = document.querySelectorAll('li');

for (var ix = 0; ix < entries.length; ix++) {
    var name = entries[ix].querySelector('.name').innerText;
    var surname = entries[ix].querySelector('.surname').innerText;
    results.push({
        name: name,
        surname: surname
    });
}

console.log(results);
```

```html
<ul class="random">
    <li class="list">
        <div class="name">John</div>
        <div class="surname">Lewis</div>
    </li>
    <li class="list odd">
        <div class="name">Nick</div>
        <div class="surname">Kyrgios</div>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: I know how to done this without nightwatch, but can't find any solution for that. Thanks anyway!